# Equivalence between sin/cos and e^ix

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

The arithmetic properties of the sets defined by e^ix and the sets defined by sin/cos are isomorphic and map 1-1 so it helps to convert sin/cos and use i in computations instead, but is there any actual equivalence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)
\mapsto
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(x) & -\sin(x)\\
\sin(x) & \cos(x)
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Therefore, a map will be
$$
e^{ix}\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}\Re e^{ix}&-\Im e^{ix}\\\Im e^{ix}&\Re e^{ix}\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Please do not answer questions that do not meet the [quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).